# Have two selector in one each() can't reach with this:first-child and this:second-child

Tags: jquery, this, each

I have the following code:

```
var tabla_szam = 1;
var etk_szam = 1;
$(".etrend_ossze, .tabla_sel").each(function () {
   if (etk_szam == 5) {
      tabla_szam++;
      etk_szam = 1;
   }
$((this).find(":first-child")).attr("id", "tabla_" + tabla_szam + "_" + etk_szam); //i want to reach the actual .etrend_ossze and .tabla_sel
$((this).find(":second-child")).attr("id", "tabla_sel" + tabla_szam + "_" + etk_szam);
etk_szam++;
});
```

The Console gives me this error: TypeError: this.find is not a function. i want to reach the actual .etrend_ossze  and the actual .tabla_sel through $this as first and second element.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$((this).find(":first-child"))
$((this).find(":second-child"))
```

by

```
$(this).find(":first-child")
$(this).find(":nth-child(1)") //:second-child doesn't exist
```

Comment: I just realize this has effect of the first and second child of .etrend_ossze and  what I want is the first and second element of this, which is .etrend_ossze and .tabla_sel   Sorry for my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at this line:

```
$((this).find(":first-child"))
```

Now let's break it up a bit:

```
$(
    (this).find(":first-child")
)
```

So the browser first does `(this)` (which returns the DOM element object) and then tries to call `find`. It would only call the jQuery function `$` on the result of the call to `find`. However, it never gets as far as calling `$`, because there is no `find` method on a native DOM element, so there is an error, as you show.

The solution is to get rid of the extra brackets:

```
$(this).find(":first-child")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way:

```
 $((this).find(":first-child")).attr("id".....
```

It should be:

Either this way:

```
$(this).find(":first-child").attr("id"....
```

or this way:

```
$(":first-child",this).attr("id".....
```

Hmmm...But, i never heard or read of `:second-child`